# How to rotate plain images using Raphaël?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, raphael

This may or may not be a very trivial question, but then again, I'm completely new to this JavaScript library (i.e. only started reading about it today). 
Exactly how do I proceed to rotating a simple image (png/jpeg etc) on my server using Raphaël? Does it need to first be converted to SVG beforehand? 
In other words, I would need to replicate [this demo](http://raphaeljs.com/image-rotation.html) on http://raphaeljs.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would put your image on the canvas and apply a rotate transform to it. Here's an example:

```
var paper = Raphael("thepaper", 300, 300);
var theImage = paper.image("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zg08b.png", 0, 0, 128, 128);
theImage.transform("R45");
```

You can see a working demo of that [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vcsjones/eMgbz/4/).

You can animate that pretty easily by applying an [animation](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.animate). Change the last line to this:

```
theImage.animate({"transform": "R45"}, 10000);
```

You can see that working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vcsjones/DxygP/1/), and that will rotate it 45 degrees over 10 seconds.